# C# .Net 6.0 App's Console.WriteLine not output to /bin/bash on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker, console

I'm running into trouble with the following steps:

1. Create a simple C# .net 6 console app with the Hello World boilerplate, and publish the portable binaries locally.
2. Create a docker container based on *mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0*
3. Copy the publish results to the container in a `consoleapp` directory.
4. Open an interactive session to the container
5. Execute `/consoleapp/ConsoleApp1.exe`

No error, but no result. Here's the (only) code in the app:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
```

I'm expecting to see:

```
Hello, World!
```

I feel like I'm missing something incredibly simple...any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that I executed chmod 777 on this, but I'm running as root anyhow.

Comment: Does it print anything when you run it under Windows?

Comment: Yep, "Hello, World!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.exe` file is only for Windows. In the container (running on Linux) you start your app with

```
dotnet ConsoleApp1.dll
```

In this case your `Dockerfile` would look like this:

```docker
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0

WORKDIR /app
COPY bin/Release/net6.0/publish/* .

CMD ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

Comment: Dur. I knew this was something simple. Thanks.

Comment: For future searchers - I was mixing up the Self-Contained deployment with the Framework-dependent publish mode. Publishing to Linux-x64 with self-contained works, though you drop the .exe on the command to execute.